# PHP krsort to custom sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'll do my best to explain this, and apologise if this is already out there...

I am attempting to replace certain strings within a paragraph, in a defined sequence.

The paragraph:

```
$Paragraph = "This bit of Water has an Apple, a pseudo Apple; some Rubber and a Big Rubber too.";
```

I have an array of strings:

```
$SortableArray = array(
                        "Apple"=>"Green Apple",
                        "Big Rubber"=>,"Big Gasket"
                        "Rubber"=>"Gasket",
                        "pseudo Apple"=>"Banana",
                        "Water"=>"Blue Water"
                    );
```

So I then `krsort` which I have to sort by key in reverse order, to try and catch the `pseudo Apple`:

```
$SortableArray = array(
                        "Water"=>"Blue Water",
                        "pseudo Apple"=>"Banana",
                        "Rubber"=>"Gasket",
                        "Big Rubber"=>,"Big Gasket"
                        "Apple"=>"Green Apple"
                    );
```

But that causes an error with the `Rubber/Big Rubber` string.

> This bit of Blue Water has an Green Apple, a Banana; some Single
>   Gasket and a Big Single Gasket too.

I am a bit stuck when I need to make sure that `Big Rubber` comes before `Rubber` in resorting the array in order to obtain the following result:

```
$Paragraph = "This bit of Water has an Apple, a pseudo Apple; some Rubber and a Big Rubber too.";

$SortableArray = array(
                        "Water"=>"Blue Water",
                        "pseudo Apple"=>"Banana",
                        "Big Rubber"=>"Big Gasket",
                        "Rubber"=>"Single Gasket",
                        "Apple"=>"Green Apple"                      
                    );

foreach ($SortableArray as $Find=>$Replace){
    $Paragraph = str_replace($Find, $Replace, $Paragraph);
}
echo $Paragraph;
```

> This bit of Blue Water has an Green Apple, a Banana; some Single
>   Gasket and a Big Gasket too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`uksort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) and sort by key length (longest to shortest):

```
uksort($SortableArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
```

Adding this before your `foreach` loop, I get the following output:

> This bit of Blue Water has an Green Apple, a Banana; some Single Gasket and a Big Gasket too.

Comment: Thanks dude. That's the logic I was after. I need to sort the array, so this is the correct answer I am looking for.

Comment: @JustBaron, as much as I like the green checkmark, Nick's answer is much cleaner and works 'out of the box.'

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect match for the 2-parameter form of [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), which replaces longest keys first:

```
$Paragraph = "This bit of Water has an Apple, a pseudo Apple; some Rubber and a Big Rubber too.";

$SortableArray = array(
                        "Apple"=>"Green Apple",
                        "Rubber"=>"Single Gasket",
                        "pseudo Apple"=>"Banana",
                        "Big Rubber"=>"Big Gasket",
                        "Water"=>"Blue Water"
                    );

echo strtr($Paragraph, $SortableArray);
```

Output:

> This bit of Blue Water has an Green Apple, a Banana; some Single
> Gasket and a Big Gasket too.

[Demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/SNG21559)